# Framework licences for Windows forms applications

Tags: .net, licensing

Probably a very simple answer to this. I have a question around licencing for frameworks used in .NET Windows forms applications. If you use a 3rd party framework within your application, for example this Bluedot mFLY! framework http://mfly.codeplex.com/ , would the end user need to purchase multiple licences to use the application on their devices?
Sorry if this is a stupid question, I just don't really understand licencing.
Thanks

Comment: The only people who can accurately answer licensing questions regarding any particular product is the vendor themselves, I suggest you give them a shout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That highly depends on the libraries you're using. Every one can have (and will have) a different license.

For the specific product, you see the licensing terms here: http://mfly.codeplex.com/license. In short: For this library, you might distribute it freely to your customers, even if you sell your product. You should not charge something for the library itself, though. And you must include the copyright notice in your product and offer anybody buying your product to get the source code of the library (not your product).